# trying to store a text file into an array

Tags: arrays, c, file, character

i am trying to read from a text file and store it into an array character by character, ive tested it out by trying to print or check the ii count but it doesn't seem to be storing, any help would be muchly appreciated

```
char *readFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* f;
    int ii = 0;

    char* file = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    char ch =  '\0';

    f = fopen(filename,"r");

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file '%s'.\n", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        {
            printf("%c",ch);

            file[ii] = (char) ch;
            ii++;

        } 

    }
 /* file[ii] = '\0'; setting last character as null*/
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);
    free(file);
    return file;
}
```

Comment: You are returning `file` from your function after calling `free` on it. In other words, you're returning an invalid pointer from your function.

Comment: @GovindParmar without the free, i get a seg fault error

Comment: @aminooo you should not call **free** before returning from the function. Maybe you are getting a segmentation fault due to some other reasons.

Comment: `char ch`?  `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Answer (score 0):

I have commented out the line containing the code to *free* the character array before returning, which was basically making the pointer invalid. I have also changed the type of the variable **"ch"** to int as **fgetc()** returns integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *readFile(char* filename)
{
    FILE* f;
    int ii = 0;

    char* file = (char*)malloc(1000*sizeof(char));
    int ch; //changed to int from char. 

    f = fopen(filename,"r");

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file '%s'.\n", filename);
    }
    else
    {
        while ((ch = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        {
           // printf("%c",ch);

            file[ii] = (char) ch;
            ii++;

        } 

    }
 /* file[ii] = '\0'; setting last character as null*/
    printf("\n");
    fclose(f);
    //free(file); //commented this line out
    return file;
}
int main()
{
  char *filename = "sample.txt";
  char *file_arr = readFile(filename);
  printf("%s \n",file_arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: An answer should consist of more than just code. Where was OP's mistake and how does this code address it?